# how to create Line chart using chart control in visual studio 2008

Tags: charts, c#-3.0, webforms, asp.net-charts

I downloaded the MSchart.exe for visual studio 2008 version..
when ever i choose the chart control it shows the bar chart only but i want to implement in line chart with X and Y-axises.

consider On y-axis the values are in mm from 1 to 1400 value range.On x-axis date/time.

I am novice in this chart control how can i create line graph using chart control in webforms?

any suggestion to do it!?

Answer (score 2):

After you have added the series,

```
series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]
properties --- series --- chart type  --- good luck :)